# MySQL Reference Top Level Table from SubQuery

Tags: mysql

I have a sub select statement in my MySQL statement that just refuses to know what the top level table/column reference is.

this is the first time I have been dealing with MySQL and it seems there are some limitations when referencing a  table and column within sub queries (note this query structure works perfectly well in sql server 2008)

here is my query:

```
select 
plugin_thold_log.id as id, 
plugin_thold_log.host_id as hostname, 
from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time) as time,
CASE
  when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id <     plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '1393603200' and a.time <= '1394121600' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time)) is null then 1
  when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '1393603200' and a.time <= '1394121600' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time)) > 30 then 1
  when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '1393603200' and a.time <= '1394121600' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time)) < 30
    and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(c.time) from (select time from plugin_thold_log b where b.id < id and b.time >= '1393603200' and b.time <= '1394121600' order by b.id desc LIMIT 7) c order by 1 asc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time)) < 30 then 0
  when TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(a.time) from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id and a.time >= '1393603200' and a.time <= '1394121600' order by a.id desc LIMIT 1), from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time)) < 30
    and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,(select from_unixtime(c.time) from (select time from plugin_thold_log b where b.id < id and b.time >= '1393603200' and b.time <= '1394121600' order by b.id desc LIMIT 7) c order by 1 asc LIMIT 1),from_unixtime(plugin_thold_log.time)) is null then 0
else 1 end as timebracket
from plugin_thold_log
where plugin_thold_log.time >= '1393603200' and plugin_thold_log.time <= '1394121600'
order by 1
```

I wont go into detail in what the query does (suffice to say it places a 1 when it finds a new log entry. However when reference plugin_thold_log.id within the subquery inside the timestampdiff function I get an error saying that the column plugin_thold_log.id is unknown in the where clause.

It seems that MySQL loses the top level table reference when place into a second level subquery.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If I see and understand it right

```
when ** from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < plugin_thold_log.id **
```

then the second plugin_thold_log should reference the other table? In that case you should give it an alias:

```
select
plugin_thold_log.id as id, 
plugin_thold_log.host_id as hostname,
**
from plugin_thold_log p
where **
order by 1
```

and then use it in your subqueries:

```
when ** from plugin_thold_log a where a.id < p.id **
```

Reason is, that afaik, if you only use the table name (plugin_thold_log) in a subquery, then it will always reference it as this subqueries instance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. But I also tried this and it still doesn't retain the reference to the first level table. This works ok for the second level query but when I get down to the third level query it cant find the top level table reference.